# solvable word problem without algorithm

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lo.logic, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. I wonder if there are examples where:

1) The word problem is known to be solvable in $G$ but there is no algorithm known.

2) The word problem is known to be solvable in $G$ but it is also known that no algorithm for solving the problem can be exhibite.

3) the same as 1) and 2) but with other decisional problems.

$\ $

Is 2) really possible? The question relies on the difference between "$\exists x$" and "showing an $x$". It seems to me that if $G$ has solvable problem then, by definition, an algorithm $A$ that solves the problem exists. Since algorithms are build up from finite objects, in principle I can enumerate all of them and eventually find $A$ (but how can I be sure that $A$ solves the word problem for $G$?). Am I making a big confusion or the question makes sense?

Comment: 2) should be formulated in a way to make sense, what's the input? Right now it sounds like "given a non-empty subset of positive integers, can we exhibit an element in this set?"

Comment: Do you mean is there a fg group with a solvable word problem but for which it is undecidable if a Turing machine accepts the word problem?

Comment: Basically there is a big difference between knowing an algorithm exists and constructing it.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg there are such examples?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg The fact that it is undecidable if a Turing machine accepts the word problem, implies that we cannot exhibit any algorithm to solve the problem. Right?

Comment: It means you can't determine if the Turing machine you are exhibiting is the correct one or not.

Comment: For example, there is a TM that gets correct the question of whether Riemann hypothesis is true.  Either it is the TM that always says "yes" or the TM that always says "no".  I can exhibit both, but I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: In your case things are even worse.  For any fixed TM M which always halts, there is no algorithm to determine given a TM as input whether it accepts the same set as M. Since finitely presented groups are as general as Turing machines, as John Stillwell points out, you cannot decide if a given TM decides the word problem for  your group.

Comment: @YCor There are in fact similar results to (2) in graph theory; the Robertson-Seymour theorem essentially says that every family of graphs that's closed under the operation of taking minors is the compliment of a union of cones, but there can be no algorithm for taking a description of a minor-closed family and producing the minimal elements of its compliment; see http://mathoverflow.net/a/48025/7092

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'm aware that these kind of results exist, but they ought to be stated in a proper way, which is, I'm afraid, not the case. What's the input? A "f.g. group with solvable word problem" is not an input. Should it be understood that the input is a recursive presentation and the question is whether, when the resulting group has solvable word problem, the output provides a algorithm? Possibly there are other interpretations of the question, and for this reason I don't consider it's asked in a proper way.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathoverflow.net/q/14918/1946. See also http://mathoverflow.net/a/126647/1946, and http://mathoverflow.net/a/48031/1946.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg thank you. May I take a little more of your time? If I understand, given a fixed G it is possible that the WP is solvable for G but $(*)$  "there is no algorithm that decides whether a TM M solves the problem". Is that right? If so,  is $(*)$ coherent with the possibility that I could prove, for a given explicit particular TM, that it solves the WP for my given G?  Or $(*)$ means that there is no way at all, given an explicit TM, to see that it solves the WP problem?

Comment: It means there is no algorithm to determine on input a TM whether it solves your problem. You might be able to prove for a single TM it works.

Comment: The closest thing two 2) that could happen is we prove in some theory (like ZFC) that $G$ is solvable, but there not being an explicit algorithm that ZFC proves is correct.

Answer (score 8):

The technique for constructing groups with unsolvable word problems
applies more generally to construct groups that "simulate'' Turing
machines. So, if a Turing machine halts for a recursive set of inputs,
it can be arranged that the corresponding group will have a solvable word problem. However,
the algorithm will depend on the set of inputs for which the machine
halts.

This reduces question 1) to finding a Turing machine which halts for
a recursive set of inputs, but for which the set itself is not yet
known. You could take, for example, a machine that halts on input 0
if there is an odd perfect number, and does not halt at all if not.